# Database Hotel Reservation

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2012

So i have a bit of a problem, on my ASP.Net website i want it to show all the rooms which are currently available and not in use. When i say not in use i mean at present there is no one reserved to that room, so the systemdate is not between any values of the checkin and checkoutdate.

Part of my schema:

```
    CREATE TABLE "Rooms"(

    RoomNo int NOT NULL,
    RoomType nvarchar(20) NULL,
    PricePerNight money NULL,
    MaximumOccupancy int NULL,
    NoOfBeds int NULL,
    NoOfBathrooms int NULL,
    Entertainment bit NULL,
    RoomService bit NULL,
    Gym bit NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_Rooms PRIMARY KEY(RoomNo)
)
CREATE TABLE "Reservation"(

    ReservationID int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
    CustomerID int NOT NULL,
    RoomNo int NOT NULL,
    CheckInDate date NOT NULL,
    CheckOutDate date NOT NULL,
    NoOfDays int NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_Reservation PRIMARY KEY(ReservationID),

    CONSTRAINT FK_Reservation_Customers_CustID FOREIGN KEY(CustomerID)  
        REFERENCES dbo.Customers(CustomerID),

    CONSTRAINT FK_Reservation_Rooms_RoomNo FOREIGN KEY(RoomNo)
        REFERENCES dbo.Rooms(RoomNo)
)
```

So heres my idea, im assuming im going to need an sql query which goes something like this:

> Select All FROM Rooms Where &CheckInDate != "Select CheckIndate From
>   Reservation" AND &CheckOutDate != "Select CheckOutDate From
>   Reservation".

But this has some flaws in it.

Can someone please tell me how i can do this, how i can make my Sue-do-code (lets call it) more viable, as i'm not sure if something like that will work, and if necessarily suggest improvements i could make to my schema.

TLDR; i need a query where someone enters a checkindate and checkoutdate and it returns all the rooms which are available.

Comment: I've come up with something else, may have gone the wrong way the first time. SELECT dbo.Rooms.RoomNo
FROM dbo.Rooms JOIN dbo.Reservation
ON (dbo.Rooms.RoomNo = dbo.Reservation.RoomNo)
WHERE GETDATE() NOT BETWEEN dbo.Reservation.CheckInDate AND dbo.Reservation.CheckOutDate; - Would something like this work? but will it do the search uniquely to every room no?

Comment: This looks like you would grab all the room that have reservations, but with res dates not encompasing the date your are looking for. If a room does not have a reservation it will not show up on this query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

SELECT * 
FROM Rooms
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT * 
 FROM Room r, Reservation rs 
 WHERE r.RoomNo = rs.RoomNo AND GETDATE() BETWEEN rs.CheckInDate AND rs.CheckOutDate)

Comment: Sorry, should have read GETDATE() BETWEEN, not GETDATE() NOT BETWEEN. Just edited.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i wanted.

```
SELECT dbo.Rooms.RoomNo
FROM dbo.Rooms JOIN dbo.Reservation
ON (dbo.Rooms.RoomNo = dbo.Reservation.RoomNo)
WHERE '2012-01-01' NOT BETWEEN dbo.Reservation.CheckInDate AND dbo.Reservation.CheckOutDate
AND '2012-01-05' NOT BETWEEN dbo.Reservation.CheckInDate AND dbo.Reservation.CheckOutDate;
```

Took time but i got it in the end. the where statement initial date can be replaced with &Date.